# e4 RCP application, ActionContributionItem leak in menus

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

The following works in Eclipse 3.7 RCP application - drop down a popup menu when clicked in a table row.

```
private void hookContextMenu(TableViewer viewer) {
    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("drillDownPopup");
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
           //.. add bunch of actions to IMenuManager
        }
    });

    Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
    viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
    getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
}
```

When this runs in e4 (Neon, latest update) none of the `ActionContributionItem` instances get GC'ed which creates quite a substantial leak when there are many items each holding references to some other objects.

Am I doing something wrong in e4?

Comment: This isn't e4. You have a 3.x compatibility mode app running on Eclipse 4.

Comment: OK. It is e3 app running in e4 target. Do you know how to stop the leak?

Comment: Code like this is all over the place in Eclipse and I haven't seen any reports of leaks. This is pretty much all JFace code which is one of the few areas that hasn't really changed.

Comment: There are reports of similar issues here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435274 I am with profiler right now,  with every right click I get count of ActionContributionItem's growing.

Comment: That bug was closed as fixed in 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to greg-449 comment above.

I want to post the screenshot profiling Eclipse Neon itself. What you see below is a counter of instances of `org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem` in running Eclipse instance. Where the slope goes up is me doing right clicks in source code editor showing drop down context menu. Every single right click leaves behind orphaned contribution items. Those will never get GC'ed. If one clicks longer, the JVM will just die with no heap left.

[image]

This is exactly what happens in my RCP application with the code snippet shown in the question. My contribution items refer to much heavier objects which bring JVM down much faster. Right now I am looking for some solution to stop the leak.